# error when installing a nextjs project, I can't solve it in any way

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, npx, create-nuxt-app

I tried installing next, I even updated the npm version to be able to create a react project with the new nextjs but it always gives the same error.

```
Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
 Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:713:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\Bruno Adler\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\cc2145a2fe1558fa\node_modules\create-next-app\dist\index.js:44:7594)
    at C:\Users\Bruno Adler\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\cc2145a2fe1558fa\node_modules\create-next-app\dist\index.js:325:18946
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\Bruno Adler\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\cc2145a2fe1558fa\node_modules\create-next-app\dist\index.js:325:18439)
    at installTemplate (C:\Users\Bruno Adler\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\cc2145a2fe1558fa\node_modules\create-next-app\dist\index.js:325:23294)
    at async createApp (C:\Users\Bruno Adler\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\cc2145a2fe1558fa\node_modules\create-next-app\dist\index.js:325:26077)
    at async run (C:\Users\Bruno Adler\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\cc2145a2fe1558fa\node_modules\create-next-app\dist\index.js:325:34922) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
```

Comment: can you provide the commands you used. it helps if we can reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0):

clean the cache `npm cache clean --force` than `npx clear-npx-cache` and run again `npx create-react-app my-app`